# VScode: How to debug a python 2.7 cgi script?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cgi

I have lighttpd web server running on my Windows 7 pc using port 80. My web app calls python cgi scripts. I am trying to configure VScode to debug these python scripts when I click a button on one of my html pages. For example:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/instantlight.py?Input=&lightColor=blue
```

In my launch.json file I have:

```
{
  "name": "Python: Attach",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "port": 80,
  "secret": "my_secret",
  "host": "localhost"
}
```

When I launch the debugger and click a button, my breakpoint is never hit. After a minute or two I get the error message "**Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly**"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to attach to a running process as you're launching the server yourself locally (you only need attach if you're attaching to a server you don't start up yourself). So you can use the e.g. `Python: Current File` configuration.

Comment: I am not starting the server myself, lighttpd is running as a process. The lighttpd.conf file points to a server.document-root folder containing html files. So a page loads with buttons on it. When I click a button, it runs a python script (see example in the OP). My question is how do I hit a breakpoint in the script that is launched by this click?

Comment: Brett: I've read this page multiple times. I can debug scripts that I launch using vscode, it's the scripts that get launched by my web app that I can't seem to attach to.

Comment: You can try using the experimental debugger, but do make sure to install the latest version of the debugger on the server to access with `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --pre ptvsd`.